# Error in python 2.7 imports on urllib2,re and base64

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a python file which runs okay on my local computer but logs these errors on my server Python 2.7.9 (default) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)] on linux2

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<dir>/kb_log.py", line 8, in <module>
    import urllib2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 92, in <module>
    import base64
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 8, in <module>
    import re
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 62
    for t in _equivalences for i in t}
```

when i fire the Python Shell on my server and import urllib2 i get not errors

***Edited*** 
The code python code triggering the errors is

```
import urllib2
import time
import socket
import smtplib


from django.core.mail import send_mail


message = {404:"The Page not found possibly a missing",
            "slow":"The site is very slow",
            502:"502 Gateway either I restarted the server or it's not responding",
            504:"Server is down :("}
    address = "myemail@gmail.com"      

def test_speed(url="mydress",timeouttest=2):     
    try:
        begin_time = time.time()
        requesttest = urllib2.urlopen(url,None,timeouttest)
        requesttest.read()
        return "Site is okay with a response time of {0}".format(time.time() - begin_time)
    except socket.timeout:
        return message["slow"]   
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        return message[e.code]
def send_email():
    result = test_speed()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login("mail@gmail.com", "xdjmfppkffwmiwvh")
    server.sendmail("mail1@gmail.com", ['mail@gmail.com','mail2@gmail.com'], result)
    server.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    send_email()
```

Comment: What are in lines 1-7 in kb_log.py?

Comment: Sounds like you're running your code with an old version of python and not the 2.7 that you have installed. That kind of error is what you will get with python 2.6 or earlier.

Comment: @noamk in path is python2.7

Comment: Please show `kb_log.py` file, how You run on server?

Comment: i have added the kb_log.py file's code